# Python Class Desgin

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

Need some help.

My code skeleton at the moment looks like this:

```
import math
epsilon = 0.000001

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
```

Need to add a method, called dist_to_point that takes another point object, p, as an argument and returns the euclidean distance between the two points. I can use math.sqrt.

Test case:

```
abc = Point(1,2)
def = Point(3,4)
abc.dist_to_point(def) ===> 2.8284271
```

how do i do this? very confused. thanks.

edit: Not homework. i understand adding methods but i dont know how to do the euclidean distance calculation coupled with the self._x and such. i get confused there

Comment: How do you do *what*, exactly? Add a method? You've already written one, `__init__`. Calculate the distance? It's a simple equation.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I don't think he wrote that, I think it was given as part of the assignment.

Comment: Not homework. i understand adding methods but i dont know how to do the euclidean distance calculation coupled with the self._x and such. i get confused there

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is it that you dont understand

Comment: also, you cannot use `def` ask a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say this isn't homework, then a direct answer is called for.  Here's some working code:

```
import math
epsilon = 0.000001

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
    def dist_to_point(self, other):
        'Compute the Euclidean distance between two Point objects'
        delta_x = self._x - other._x
        delta_y = self._y - other._y
        return (delta_x ** 2 + delta_y ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Sample session:

```
>>> point_abc = Point(1,2)
>>> point_def = Point(3,4)
>>> point_abc.dist_to_point(point_def)
2.8284271247461903
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a method with the signature `dist_to_point(self, p)`.  In that method, you will need to implement the formula for distance between two points in two-space (which is available from Wikipedia, among other sources).

Within your method, you can refer to the coordinates of the *called* point as `self._x` and `self._y`.  The coordinates of the *argument* point will be `p._x` and `p._y`.

Is that enough to get you started?